# PsychoPy- event.getKeys() is not correctly recording a list of keypresses

Tags: events, psychopy

I am trying to have the user be able to adjust the length of a line displayed in psychopy by either pressing the up or down keys. I am using event.getKeys(), however, it is not recording the keys that are pressed. I am not sure why, but it always shows an empty list of keys. This is my code:

```
class line(object):
    def makeLine(self,length):
        line = visual.Line(win=win,ori=-45,lineRGB=[-1,-1,-1],lineWidth=3.0, fillRGB=None,
                 pos= [0,0],interpolate=True,opacity=1.0,units='cm',size=length)
        #describes the line 
        return line.draw()

line2length=2#original length of the line 
line2=line()#makes line2 an instance of line class 
line2.makeLine(line2length)#calls the makeLine function of the line class 
win.flip()#updates the window
keys = event.getKeys()
expInfo['KeyPress']=keys 
event.waitKeys(['return'])
print keys        
for key in keys: 
    if 'up' in key:
        line2length+=.5
        line2.makeLine(line2length)
        win.flip()
    if 'down' in keys:
        line2length-=.5
        line2.makeLine(line2length)
        win.flip()

event.clearEvents()
thisExp.nextEntry()
```

Answer (score 3):

`psychopy.event.getKeys()` returns a list of keys since the event module was instantiated OR since last `getKeys()` call OR since `event.clearEvents()`. It returns `None` if no keyboard events were registered in this frame.

In your case, the subject probably had around 0.1 seconds to press before it reached the `event.getKeys()` line because there's nothing time-padding between, like a core.wait or multiple `win.flip()`'s.

I do suspect that you really want to use `event.waitKeys()` which waits for the first keyboard event and returns that. This guarantees that there's always exactly one key in the list returned.

Some other comments to your code:

1. Look at the demos in coder --> demos --> stimuli to see how to present ShapeStims (Line, Rect, Circle etc. are all ShapeStims). You will see that instantiation and drawing should be done differently and much simpler. In particular, you're instantiating a full stimulus several times on each trial when you really should just draw it (much faster and cleaner).
2. No need to loop through `keys` when you're looking for particular values. Just do ``if 'up' in keys.

Here's a revised code, which might be closer to what you want:

```py
# Create stimulus. Heavy stuff
line = visual.Line(win=win,ori=-45,lineRGB=[-1,-1,-1],lineWidth=3.0, fillRGB=None,
    pos= [0,0],interpolate=True,opacity=1.0,units='cm',size=length)

# Change attribute, light stuff
line.size = 2  # set length

# Present stimulus
line.draw()
win.flip()

# Register responses after approximately 1 second (time by frames if you want exact timing) and have an extra "return"
core.wait(1)
keys = event.getKeys(['up', 'down'])  # you probably want to restrict which keys are valid? Otherwise you have to react to invalid keys later - which is also ok.
event.waitKeys(['return'])

# React to response (no win-flip here, I assume that you only need this change on next trial, where the above win.flip() will execute
if keys != None:
    if 'up' in keys:
        line.length += 0.5
    if 'down' in keys:
        line.length -= 0.5
else:
    pass  # you can do something explicitly on missing response here.

# Mark change of trial
thisExp.nextEntry()
```