# first keypress is ignored

Tags: javascript, keydown, keyup

Summarize the problem:
(New to js - I tried to find the answer on here, but I am unsure whether I don't understand keybehavior or whether my code is wonky.)
I am trying to move objects on the screen. Instead of reacting on the keydown or keyup (I tried both), the object only moved once I hit another key. This would be fine for object movement, but I also try to lock the response once spacebar is pressed, which also is not working.

This is using Chrome Version 81.0.4044.92 on a Macbook Pro

Describe what you’ve tried:
I tried using both keyup and keydown.

When appropriate, show some code:

```
var angle;
var myx;
var myy;
var LocCol;
var LocCol2;
var _resp_test_allKeys;
var TestComponents;
// FRR ----- manual entry BEGIN; copy this before "function TestRoutineBegin(trials) {" 
// code to move stimulus
var xforce; 

xforce = 0; // initially set speed ('force') to 0. It increases in steps of 1 as long as key is down

function  resetXforce(event){
    xforce = 0 // if finger has been lifted, go back to speed 0
}
function  getKeyResponse(event){ // check for responses
        var thisResp = psychoJS.eventManager.getKeys();
        console.log(thisResp)
        if ("left" == thisResp[0]) {
                xforce--;  // decrease angle with increasing acceleration the longer key pressed
                angle = (angle + xforce); //plus not minus here since xforce may become negative
                myx = (0.25 * Math.sin((((Math.PI * 2) * angle) / 360)));
                myy = (0.25 * Math.cos((((Math.PI * 2) * angle) / 360)));
                //smallcircle2.setPos([myx, myy]);
                image_on_circ_test.setPos([myx, myy]);

                }
        if ("right" == thisResp[0]) {
                xforce++; //increase angle with increasing acceleration the longer key pressed
                angle = (angle + xforce);
                myx = (0.25 * Math.sin((((Math.PI * 2) * angle) / 360)));
                myy = (0.25 * Math.cos((((Math.PI * 2) * angle) / 360)));
                //smallcircle2.setPos([myx, myy]);
                image_on_circ_test.setPos([myx, myy]);
            }
    // for some reason this only responds on second keypress? 
    /* if ("space" == thisResp[0]) {
            LocCol2 = 'white'  // if response locked with spacebar
        } */

    if (psychoJS.eventManager.getKeys({keyList:['space']}).length > 0) {
        LocCol2 = 'white'  // if response locked with spacebar
        }

        //psychoJS.eventManager.clearEvents({eventType:'keyboard'});
    }
document.addEventListener("keydown", getKeyResponse); //tried keydown as well, with the same problem
document.addEventListener("keyup", resetXforce);
// FRR ----- manual entry END -----
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24044474/12894605 Seems like someones have in a similar issue with the python version of psycho. Have you tried using the bare bones event.keyup/keydown as an alternative.

Comment: hello , i looked through the eventManager of psychoJS https://psychopy.github.io/psychojs/core_EventManager.js.html#line54   search for _addKeyListeners,, you will see the keydown event is attach to the window object in the bubbling phase because the boolean of capture is not set and Standard is(false bubbling phase).   if an event occurs first the capturing phase starts and it goes from window to document then we have the target phase and then bubbling phase form document to window and you set your keydown event on document , so your event fires before the eventManager notice the event

Comment: the target is always body  window->document->body body->document->window (Exception input)

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' thanks so much. I don't think I understand the answer fully (certainly have to read up on the bubbling - coming from Matlab js is confusing!), but it pointed me in the right direction I think. At least changing document to window solved to problem!

Comment: @StephenDuffy thanks for the link as well!